# Why "val a=-1" doesn't work in scala?

Tags: scala

I found `val a = -1` works well in scala REPL, but if I skip the space around the `=` like `val a=-1`, the expression doesn't return the result.

Does anyone have ideas about this? Why the space arount the `=` is necessary here?

Answer (score 6):

`=-` is a legitimate method name in Scala; the following will work:

```
class A {
  def =-(i: Int) = i
}
val a = new A
a=-1
```

So the parser can't distinguish your `val a=-1` from this case.

Comment: but `=-` is not a legitimate method of `Int`, shouldn't scala know how to parse this expression correctly?

Comment: There might be an implicit conversion from `Int` to some object with an `=-` method. And in general parsing (in this case technically lexing) happens at a very early stage in compilation, long before it knows what type expressions have, or even which parts of the source text are expressions.

Comment: @Imm In this case, your explanation is for `a=-1` , which has nothing to do with actual question `val a=-1`

Comment: @ShyamendraSolanki I suspect this is happening at the lexing stage, before that distinction becomes relevant.

Answer (score 2):

`val` is used in 2 cases:

1) value declaration:

```
val a = 2
> a: Int = 2
```

2) pattern definition:

```
val Some(x) = Some(2)
> x: Int = 2
```

when you write `val a=-1`, it clearly fails to match the "value declaration" syntax, so the compiler attempts "pattern definition" syntax.

To see this is the case, let's put a semi-colon in the end of the line.

```
 val a=-1 ;
 > <console>:1: error: '=' expected but ';' found.
```

Indeed, the compiler is looking for the right hand side of pattern definition.

Now notice that `=-` is a valid identifier name. 
So if it is a case class (or a normal class with unapply method), it can be used in pattern
match syntax.

Let's see if this actually works:

```
case class =- (i: Int, j: Int)
> defined class $eq$minus

val a =- b = =-(2, 3)  // infix syntax for pattern match
> a: Int = 2
  b: Int = 3

// Yes. it works!

// This is same as:
val =-(a, b) = =-(2, 3)
```

Comment: What is the reason of `when you write val a=-1, it clearly fails to match the "value declaration" syntax`?